# How to zoom in/out using mouse wheel?

Tags: macos, mouse

Using Yosemite, I want to use CMD + mouse wheel up/down in order to zoom in/out(CMD +/- equivalent).

How can it be achieved?

Comment: In what apps? Safari? TextEdit? System-wide font?

Comment: updated question.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + mouse wheel in most cases doesn't increase the font size, it's usually in most circumstances a 'zoom' in. Increasing the font size system wide isn't possible without setting it specifically for Applications (if you know the menu title) in keyboard shortcuts. However, you can emulate a system wide zoom in level with a double tap of the mouse (if your using magic mouse) by turning that system feature on in:

System Prefs > Mouse > Smart Zoom

Or you can take advantage of Accessibility feature which is turned on by default by zooming the window in:

<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>OPT</kbd>=

To emulate this with a mouse scroll event go to :

System Prefs > Accessibility > Zoom

You will a list of options for you customize your scroll events.

[image: pic1]

'Use Gesture Scroll Events' will be greyed out by system default. Select this option to enable it. Choose which primary key to function from, OSx will take care of the rest (directional zoom). As you can see you can customize furthermore with picture-in-picture etc to better service your need

Comment: I've updated my question to better clarify what I meant.

Comment: @Anonymous You won't be able to do this without applescript or performing shell scripts. To save you time, I would look into 3rd party apps that have already serviced this for you.

Comment: @Anonymous I digress, I remember this being a functional resource in Mavericks but have not myself used it in Yosemite now that expose and windows are more fluid with spaces, but I just confirmed it's still an option - see my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net) using the Scroll Up or Scroll Down gesture mapped to a custom keyboard shortcut of ⌘+ or ⌘-.

[image]

Comment: I want this to work with middle mouse button, not Touchpad gestures. Are you sure it will work?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, there is a separate section for mice, I simply selected trackpad for the example screenshot.

Comment: There is no way to select scroll wheel, only middle button

Comment: In the current version of BetterTouchTool, if you select "normal mouse", there is a "Click to record a mouse button" section, which works with the scroll wheel.